# Researching the complexity of a dynamic array with insert-last(x) and delete-last() operations

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures, asymptotics, arrays

In this question I need your help researching time complexity of a dynamic array with insert-last(x) and delete-last() operations:

We define a data structure and call it dynamic array, we define the operations inseet-last(x) and delete-last(), we also define a set of rules for this data structure:

Insert-last(x): inserts x to the end of the array following the set of rules bellow.

Delete-last: deleted the last element in the array follwong rhe swt of rules bellow.

1. When the data structure is full, we allocate a new array with double the size, copy all the values from the old array into the new one.
2. When the data structure is quarter full, we allocate a new array that is half the size if the old one and copy all of the values from the old array into the new one.

I proved that in this data structure, the operations of insert-last(x) and delete-last() take O(1) amortized time using the potential method, here is the function (M is the length of the array, and n is the number of elements in the arrary):

$$\Phi(M, n) = \left\{^{2n - M 
 \space \space \space n \space \ge \frac M2} _{0 \space \space \space otherwise} \right\}$$

Then, I modified the rules a bit:

1. When the array is full we allocate a new array $x1.5$ the size of the old one and copy all the values to the new array.
2. When the array is half full, we allocate a new array $x0.75$ the size of the old one and copy all the values into the new array.

With this set of rules I was also able to prove that the insert-last(x) and delete-last() operations take O(1) amortized using the potential method, here is the function:

$$\Phi(M, n) = \left\{^{3n - 2M 
 \space \space \space n \space \ge \frac M2} _{2M - 3n \space \space \space otherwize} \right\}$$

But my question is, that if we define these constants:

- $\alpha > 1$
- $\beta < 1$
- $t < \beta < 1$

And change the rules to be:

1. If the array is full we allocate a new array $* \alpha$ the size of the old array and copy all the values to the new array.
2. If the array is less than $tM$ full we allocate a new array $* \beta$ the size of the old array, and copy all the values to the new array.

I want to prove that the operations of the dynamic array using this set of rules cost O(1) amortized **using the potential method** but I cannot find a potential function that helps me to prove that, in other words, I want to find the general potential function that helps to prove that the operatios cost O(1) amortized, any help is appreciated, even if it's just an upvote, Thanks!

Edit: this is a question from a homework at University of haifa for computer science students.

Comment: 1. Please define what the insert-last and delete-last operations are.  The question doesn't say.  2. Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?  Or, what is the motivation?

Comment: @D.W. I have editted the post, I apologize for the confusion